# ECONNREFUSED takes a long time in node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to simulate a none running service and i am getting the expected error **ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:55663**. But it takes nodejs about **1000ms** to respond with that error. So my question is on what kind of setting is this duration depended on? Why does it take so long ?

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    path: '/v1/calculator/pcs',
    port: '55663',
    method : 'GET'

}, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    });
});
req.on('error', function (error) {
    console.timeEnd("myRequest");
    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
});

console.time("myRequest");
req.end();
```

**Output**

myRequest: 1012.345ms

Comment: How are you simulating the service being down?  If the host is there, but there is no server responding on the desired port, then you may be seeing a TCP connect timeout which can't be set real short because in the real world, a very busy server sometimes takes a bit of time to respond to the initial connect.  BTW, 1000ms is only a second.